Confined user (staff_u) can use sudo to transition to unconfined_r even though there is no sudoers entry that permits it
I've created a user that is mapped to the staff_u SELinux user:
# semanage login -l

Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service

__default__          unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
local                staff_u              s0                   *
root                 unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *

After the log in to the system they are in staff_r:staff_t as expected:
$ id
uid=1000(local) gid=1000(local) groups=1000(local) context=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0

I've created a sudoers entry to allow them to transition to sysadm_r:
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for local on myhost:
    [...]

User local may run the following commands on myhost:
    (ALL : ALL) ROLE=sysadm_r TYPE=sysadm_t ALL

which works as expected:
$ sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=staff_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0

However the user is also able to transition into the other roles allowed for the SELinux user:
$ sudo -u $USER -r unconfined_r -t unconfined_t id
uid=1000(local) gid=1000(local) groups=1000(local),1001(remote-access) context=staff_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0

Why is this?

This is my own guess at an answer. I am not sure it's right, it's just what I've figured out through observation.

SELinux policy defines which roles a user may transition into. staff_u may transition to staff_r, sysadm_r and a few others.
A tool such as sudo or newrole is used in order to actually transition into a new role.
A sudoers entry does not grant permission to transition into a role. It only grants permission to use the sudo command. The ROLE= and TYPE= of the entry are not granting anything; they are merely configuring a default transition to occur when sudo decides that the requesting user/host/command match the entry.
The target role/type may be overridden by the user with the -r and -t options to sudo. SELinux policy will permit/deny this, not sudo.

Putting this all together, let's change the sudoers rule to remove ROLE= and TYPE:
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for local on myhost:
    [...]

User local may run the following commands on myhost:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL

Without ROLE= and TYPE=, no transition occurs. As such, while the user can launch a process as root, it can't do very much:
$ sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0

$ sudo file /etc/shadow
/etc/shadow: cannot open `/etc/shadow' (Permission denied)

However the user can still specifically ask to transition to any role permitted for their SELinux user by policy:
$ sudo -r sysadm_r id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=staff_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0

$ sudo -r sysadm_r file /etc/shadow
/etc/shadow: ASCII text

The purpose of adding a default transition to a sudoers entry is for convenience; it would be annoying to have to remember to add -r sysadm_r every time you run sudo.
